# Customized Animation in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, core-graphics

I am creating Application which have so many Customization. Customization in the sense, I want to give new look to my application. In the part of customization I want to add [THIS](http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/124059/screenshots/976474/gif2.gif) kind of animation inside my application.

i have searched over internet finally i found so many 3d animations. But those results are not satisfy my needs.

Suggest me some piece of code to make that animation possible.

If u provide any source code, That will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly you want.Set your view like this.
_transitionFrame is label outlet.That label is placed on your display view.

Include QuartzCore framework and define a method to convert degree to radians like this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

In view did load Method write following code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect preFrame=_transitionFrame.frame;
    preFrame.origin.y+=preFrame.size.height/2;
    [_transitionFrame setFrame:preFrame];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DRotate(_transitionFrame.layer.transform,DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 1.0, 0.0,0.0);
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [_transitionFrame.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1)];
    _transitionFrame.layer.transform=_3Dt;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply., let me try it., but this animation is  seems like rotating the view. my animation is not trying to rotating the view.

Comment: you can place a view above this label and can increase or decrease height of view with animation according to rotating label.